# iptables network address translation from lan to vpn

Tags: iptables, openvpn, nat

June 13, 2018: I found a solution and have edited this post in case it is useful to someone.

**First, the original post:**

I have a portal where I want to do network address translation from its public IP address and a particular one of its public port numbers, to a particular VPN IP address and a particular VPN port number, for both TCP and UDP traffic, for RTSP-and-RTP-tunneled-over-HTTP. The problem is that no packets are getting through. The portal, in addition to running openvpn, has an apache2 server, whose proxypass and proxypassreverse statements allow me route traffic between LAN and VPN, but only for TCP traffic. Since apache2 can't handle UDP traffic, I'm trying to set up iptables to do it for me. There is just one Ethernet interface. Devices on the VPN are on the Internet, so eth0 and tun0 traffic all flow over eth0.

I have set up rules in iptables and enabled forwarding for eth0 (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/eth0/forwarding = 1`) and tun0 (`/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/tun0/forwarding = 1`), and all ('/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1'), but nothing happens.

I have added the following rules to the default iptables rules:

```
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.192.203/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 10073 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.221.0.73:80
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.192.203/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10073 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.221.0.73:80
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.221.0.73/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.192.203
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.221.0.73/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.192.203
```

and

```
-A FORWARD -d 10.221.0.73/32 -p udp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.221.0.73/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

With these rules, I'm trying to take UDP and TCP traffic from the Internet (I'm using 192.168.192.203 in this example) for port 10073 and forward it to VPN IP address 10.221.0.73 and port 80.

Here is the full ruleset:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Thu Jun  7 16:52:00 2018
*raw
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1930:216976]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1477:229328]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 8073 -j TRACE
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 8073 -j TRACE
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jun  7 16:52:00 2018

# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Thu Jun  7 16:52:00 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [462:32832]
:INPUT ACCEPT [462:32832]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [98:6069]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [98:6069]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.192.203/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 10073 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.221.0.73:80
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.192.203/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10073 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.221.0.73:80
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.221.0.73/32 -p udp -m udp --sport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.192.203
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.221.0.73/32 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -j SNAT --to-source 192.168.192.203
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jun  7 16:52:00 2018

# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Thu Jun  7 16:52:00 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1738:195868]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1333:210602]
:ufw-after-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-after-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-after-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-input - [0:0]
:ufw-before-logging-output - [0:0]
:ufw-before-output - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-forward - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-input - [0:0]
:ufw-reject-output - [0:0]
:ufw-track-input - [0:0]
:ufw-track-output - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -d 10.221.0.73/32 -p udp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.221.0.73/32 -p tcp -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu Jun  7 16:52:00 2018
```

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance.

**Second, here's how I fixed it...**

I set up tcpdump on the machine I use as a router, and on a machine that I'm forwarding traffic to. The key was to set up sufficiently broad rules for choosing relevant packets to report since other traffic was flowing through both machines, and to report with sufficient verbosity. And, to simplify things, I changed the router machine to one that was also an OpenVPN host, instead of being an OpenVPN client.

Here's the command I used on the router machine, whose LAN IP address is 192.168.192.166, and whose VPN IP address is 10.254.0.1:

```
tcpdump -n -vv -c 5000 "port 80 or port 10073 or host 10.254.0.1 or host 10.254.0.73 or (host 192.168.192.166 and port 80) or (host 192.168.192.166 and port 10073)" -i any
```

10.254.0.73 is the machine I'm forwarding packets to, using its port 80. I'm sending packets to port 10073 on the router.

Here's the command for the machine I'm forwarding packets to:

```
tcpdump -vv -n -c 5000 "port 80 or port 10073 or host 192.168.192.166 or host 10.254.0.1" -i any
```

The "-i any" picks up traffic on both my "public" port, eth0, and also my "private" port, tun0.

Here are routing rules that work for me:

```
root@B16:~# iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.8 on Wed Jun 13 14:52:56 2018
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [73673:9416551]
:INPUT ACCEPT [71740:8067234]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1933:1349317]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [120157:14972014]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [122090:16321331]
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 13 14:52:56 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.8 on Wed Jun 13 14:52:56 2018
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [12313:867446]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [11426:951748]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m udp --dport 10073 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.254.0.73:80
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 10073 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.254.0.73:80
-A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 13 14:52:56 2018
# Generated by iptables-save v1.3.8 on Wed Jun 13 14:52:56 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [71741:8067274]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [1250:1319002]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [120162:14973202]
:INBOUND - [0:0]
:LOG_FILTER - [0:0]
:LSI - [0:0]
:LSO - [0:0]
:OUTBOUND - [0:0]
-A FORWARD -d 10.254.0.73 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.254.0.73 -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Jun 13 14:52:56 2018
```

I did not find TRACE in iptables useful because it was too hard to get the right rules. Using tcpdump saved the day, ONCE I got the right rules and verbosity, because I could see when forwarding started to work, but that packets were not being returned to the router; they were being returned to the laptop that was trying to forward messages through the router. I could also see that checksum errors were occurring -- this was totally unexpected.

I read lots of conflicting posts, each with "this works for me," but they did not work for me. One problem was that iptables rules apparently are OS-dependent; I'm using Debian and that changed them for who knows why. I never could find a thorough explanation of how to construct iptables rules, just a few examples.

Cheers.

Comment: Forwarding is controlled by `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`, not by `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/tunneling`.

Comment: cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward gives 1

Comment: So you want two different services, one TCP the other UDP, listening at the same port number? And failing that, the firewall is supposed to make it work? I am missing the part what exactly isn't working or hints such as logged information or even if you see the counters for these rules going up and such.

Comment: I want to forward both tcp and udp traffic for the chosen port, same as in any router. Separately, I set up iptables TRACE statements on the routing machine and a target machine. No packets from the routing machine are received by the target machine, even though I enabled ip-forward on the routing machine, so there's clearly something wrong. UFW is present but turned off at the moment. I will double-check the counters on the routing machine...

Comment: I have a test program. On the routing machine, I see 100+ packets in the INPUT chain, a little less on the OUTPUT chain, but only 2 on the FORWARD chain. So it looks like there's something wrong with the FORWARD chain, assuming I have TRACE set up right. I trace PREROUTING (--dport) and OUTPUT (--sport) to the target port number on the routing machine.

Comment: 1/ the POSTROUTING rules are probably useless: iptables' NAT is always stateful, meaning there's no need to have a "reverse DNAT" done with the SNAT: iptables and netfilter already handle this (unless there is more than 30s for initial UDP reply). 2/ The trace on 8073, not 10073? 3/ the receiving machine will receive the internet IP through the tunnel, while its route for it is probably not through this tunnel. if that's the case, reverse path filter kicks in (incoming packets via tunnel are dropped) and replies won't flow through the tunnel anyway. use tcpdump on target

Comment: 4/ if 192.168.192.203 is the example internet IP (quoting: "from the Internet (I'm using 192.168.192.203 in this example)" ) then the rules won't match afaik. if now 192.168.192.203 is the router's IP you should edit the question to make it clear, and there's still 3/ above. You should give an example of how it was tested. even with anonymized IPs, it has to be understood if the IP is from internet or not, from the router (then not routing) or not etc.

Comment: I activated tcpdump on my test router (192.168.192.203) and on the target machine (xxx.205), and set up some host and port filters. This was very useful because I can see that packets from my laptop (xxx.211) are being forwarded correctly through the test router to the target machine, BUT the replies from the target machine are being sent to my laptop without going back through the test router. The network has a physical router at xxx.1, so I'm wondering if the problem is that I have 2 routers on my test LAN. If so, how do I tell the target machine to use xxx.203 when messages come from it ?